# Attach a base64 string as an attachment into lead object

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, base64

I have a landing page in marketing cloud which will contain a form with input fields.
One of the input field will be for a file attachment. (.pdf or image)
I will encode this file to a base64 string.

Once this form is submitted i will get the values to flow to a marketing cloud DE including the base64 string using AMPscript.

I want to then use journey builder to create a lead in Salesforce with the file attached to the lead.

Question:

Can i decode a base64 string and have it attached to the lead record in SF?
If so what field do i map the string to.

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Any solution advice at a high level is appreciated.

Comment: Comment to answer later: use automation studio to create a rest API call to Salesforce. Use the composite call. Create the lead and create an attachment and use the parentid of the attachment and store the lead id into it. Not 100% sure if this works with leads. Will post later